# The limit of $xy/(y-x^3)$ at $(0,0)$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{y-x^3}$$
doesn't exist? Obviously, if $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{y-x^3}$ and, for instance, $\gamma_1(t)=(t,0)$, we have $\lim_{t\to0}f(\gamma_1(t))=0$. We just need to find another curve $\gamma_2(t)$ with $\gamma_2(t_0)=(0,0)$ such that $\lim_{t\to t_0}f(\gamma_2(t))\neq 0$ and we are done. But, what curve to choose??

Comment: Which curves have you tried?

Comment: A lot of them. The limit always seems go to zero... :(

Comment: Did you try things that are not linear?

Comment: I just found it! At least, I think I have... $\gamma_2(t)=(t,\frac{t^3}{1-t})$ and $t\to0$.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to get a curve where the limit is $c$ is to find a curve on which the expression is constant and equals $c$. To find that curve is straightforward: The equation
$$\frac{xy}{y-x^3} = c$$
is easily solved for $y$, giving
$$y = \frac{cx^3}{c-x}$$
Now just set $x=t$, and obtain $y=\frac{ct^3}{c-t}$. One readily checks that for $t=0$ one indeed obtains $x=y=0$, so that curve goes to the origin, as required.

Therefore on the curve $\left(t,ct^3/(c-t)\right)$ you'll get
$\lim_{t->0}\frac{x(t)y(t)}{y(t)-x(t)^3} = \lim_{t\to 0} c = c$.

Since the curve is defined around $t=0$ for any $c$, the original limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I have a question for you. We know that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} = 0.$$ But, using the above method we can consider the curve $$\gamma(t) = \left( \sqrt{\frac{2t^2}{t-2}}, t \right )$$ and, in this case, we get $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{2y^2}{y-2} y}{\frac{2y^2}{y-2}+y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{2y^3}{2y^2+y^3-2y^2}=2.$$ How come? Something must be wrong!

Comment: There is a typo in the last limit above (I can not edit it anymore). It should be $y \to 0$.

Comment: @Alice: Close to $t=0$, the expression under the square root is negative, and therefore the square root is not defined in the real numbers. Since this curve does not exist close to $t=0$, it doesn't have a limit there.

Comment: Sure thing! The domain is $t=0$ and $t>2$. We can't take the limit with $t \to 0$. Thank you to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Try $y=x^3+x^4$.  Then, 
$$
\frac{xy}{y-x^3}=\frac{x^4+x^5}{x^3+x^4-x^3}=\frac{x^4+x^5}{x^4}=1+x.
$$
The reason that this works is that the $x^3$'s cancel, leaving $x^4$, which is $x$ times the smallest power in $y$.

Comment: Note that this is what you get when you substitute $c=1+x$ into celtschk's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As $ n \to \infty,(1/n,1/n^3+ 1/e^n) \to (0,0),$  while $f(1/n,1/n^3+ 1/e^n)= e^n((1/n^4)+1/(ne^n)) \to \infty.$