# Show that $f(x,y) = \frac{\sin(xy)}{|x-y|}$ has no limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. Hint try subsequences.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

Show that $f(x,y) =  \frac{\sin(xy)}{|x-y|}$ has no limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. Hint: try subsequences.

We worked part of this out in class and I'm going over it to arrive at a final solution and I'm somewhat stuck.

The first thing we did was reduce it to a one dimensional problem by letting $$g(x,mx) = \frac{\sin(mx^{2})}{|x-mx|} = \frac{\sin(mx^{2})}{|x||1-m|}$$

Which we can manipulate:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}g(x,mx) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(mx^{2})}{|x||1-m|} \frac{mx^{2}}{mx^{2}} = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$

So we showed along one path that the function goes to zero. The hint now says to show by subsequences that this function does not exist. To do that I would have to find a convergent sequence, $a_{n} \to 0$ such that the function $g(a_{n}) \nrightarrow 0$. From this I could then pick an epsilon and prove it by contradiction.

My question is how can I find this subsequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{\sin(xy)}{|x-y|}=\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\frac{xy}{|x-y|}$$

and $\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\to 1$ but for $x=2y$

$$\frac{xy}{|x-y|}=\frac{2y^2}{|y|} \to 0$$

and for $x=t+t^2$ and $y=t\to 0$

$$\frac{xy}{|x-y|}=\frac{t^2+t^3}{t^2} \to 1$$

therefore the given limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

$x_{n}=\dfrac{n}{(n+1)^{2}}$, $y_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n}$, $\sin(x_{n}y_{n})=\sin\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}$, and $|x_{n}-y_{n}|=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{2}}\left|-2-\dfrac{1}{n}\right|$, the limit as quotient goes to $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you apply user's method, for $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{|x-y|}:$ try a sequence similar to the one in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228063/721644) answer.

Let $(x_n,y_n)=\left(\frac1n+e^{-n},\frac1n\right).$
Then, $$\frac{x_ny_n}{|x_n-y_n|}=\frac{\frac1{n^2}+\frac{e^{-n}}n}{e^{-n}}=\frac{e^n}{n^2}+\frac1n\to+\infty\text{ as } n\to+\infty$$